# facing issue while executing Spring MVC web application

Tags: spring-mvc

When I run this web application. I am getting 404 error. and when I checked that url it was `http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/` instead of `http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/welcome`. Can you please help me with the issue.

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
package org.controller.com;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloworld(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }


}
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan  base-package="org.controller.com" />  

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>  
        <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
   <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

**HelloPage.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>First Spring Project</h1>
<h2> ${msg}</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? You want to display the same thing with `http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/` and `http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/welcome`? Does it work for `http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/welcome`?

Comment: I run above Spring MVC application. When I run it , it should call the URL http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/welcome as per RequestMapping("/welcome") in HelloWorldController.java. But it shows 404 error to me and the url of the page was http://localhost:9090/SpringMVC/, which means it is not able to find HelloPage.jsp.